# How can find Unicode character in mysql?

Tags: mysql, unicode

I want to find every row that have a character star in column msg and none of these query can find them:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` m WHERE m.msg like '%\u2B50%';
SELECT * FROM `mytable` m WHERE m.msg like '%/u2B50%';
SELECT * FROM `mytable` m WHERE m.msg like '%0x2B50%';
SELECT * FROM `mytable` m WHERE m.msg like '%x2B50%';
SELECT * FROM `mytable` m WHERE m.msg like concat('%',x'2B50','%');
```

- 2B50 is Unicode of star emoji
- column msg is Text by utf8_persian_ci
- I saved that character by php
- that star shows in phpmyadmin as a little square

Comment: which charset and  collation you are using  fo store values in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try UNHEX   x2b50   corresponds to utf-8   e2 ad 90

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` m WHERE m.msg LIKE CONCAT("%", UNHEX('e2ad90'), "%");
```